# MVC3 - razor : How to use mailto dynamically

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a link as bellow. Is there any way to change `info@example.co.uk` with `model.Contact.EmailAddress` to make it dynamics.

```
<a href="mailto:info@example.co.uk">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contact.EmailAddress)</a></dd>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `Contact` is a property of your model which is binded to your view, you can use it like this

```
<a href="mailto:@Model.Contact.EmailAddress">@Model.Contact.EmailAddress</a>
```

If it is a child property of your model and you want to do it inside a loop, you can do like this

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Contacts)
{
  <a href="mailto:@item.Contact.EmailAddress">@item.Contact.EmailAddress</a>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the appropriate razor syntax inline with your html as you would normally do when writing any output from your model.

```
<a href="mailto:@model.Contact.EmailAddress">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contact.EmailAddress)</a>
```